# How to solve the issue with OpenCV CUDA support building

Tags: python, opencv, cmake

Made a lot of efforts with different parameters to build the OpenCV with CUDA support but everytime got the error:

> FAILED: bin/opencv_world490.dll lib/opencv_world490.lib
> C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_dll --intdir=modules\world\CMakeFiles\opencv_world.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1438~1.331\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\opencv_world.rsp  /out:bin\opencv_world490.dll /implib:lib\opencv_world490.lib /pdb:bin\opencv_world490.pdb /dll /version:4.9 /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libc /DEBUG  && cd ."
> LINK: command "C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1438~1.331\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\opencv_world.rsp /out:bin\opencv_world490.dll /implib:lib\opencv_world490.lib /pdb:bin\opencv_world490.pdb /dll /version:4.9 /machine:x64 /INCREMENTAL:NO /NODEFAULTLIB:libc /DEBUG /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2" failed (exit code 1181) with the following output:
> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'x64.lib'

I use manual from this link: [https://www.jamesbowley.co.uk/qmd/opencv_cuda_python_windows.html]
Tried to build with Visual Studio 2019, 2022, Ninja. Made efforts with different versions of OpenCV. But no effect

Can't understand what the reason of the issue and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of problem. It was a result of the arguments I passed to CMAKE. The exact specification of -DCUDNN_LIBRARY argument as:

```
-DCUDNN_LIBRARY="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDNN\v8.9.6.50\lib\x64\cudnn.lib"
```

solved the problem.